# Python Pandas Groupby: How to Condense For Loop in a One Liner

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

For Python Pandas:

I want to simplify my code - so that it is a one liner in the end (reason: performance optimization).

How do I have to write it so that I only have one single row that contains the `groupby` statement?

Something like:

```
dfResult = df2.groupby("a").something().I()Do()Not()Understand()Yet()
```

This is my code (I want to filter out these groups of column `a` where the standard deviation between rows for `b` is too big):

```
import pandas as pd

dfResult = pd.DataFrame()

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ("w", "w", "w", "w", "x", "x", "x"), 'b': (30, 42, 54, 68, 7, 8, 65)})
print('input data:')
print(df2)
dfGroupBy = df2.groupby("a")
for key, item in dfGroupBy:
    innerDf = dfGroupBy.get_group(key)
    # calculate delta between two rows for column 'b'
    innerDf['delta'] = innerDf['b'] - innerDf['b'].shift(1)
    # calculate standard deviation (without the first row)
    standardDeviation = pd.np.std(innerDf['delta'][1:])
    if standardDeviation < 15:
        print ("so my standard deviation is small enough!")
        print(innerDf['delta'][1:])
        print("standard deviation:", standardDeviation)
        # remove column 'delta', as I needed it only in between
        innerDf = innerDf.drop('delta', axis=1)
        dfResult = dfResult.append(innerDf)

print("result:")
print(dfResult)
```

And this is the console output:

```
input data:
   a   b
0  w  30
1  w  42
2  w  54
3  w  68
4  x   7
5  x   8
6  x  65
so my standard deviation is small enough!
1    12.0
2    12.0
3    14.0
Name: delta, dtype: float64
standard deviation: 0.942809041582
result:
   a   b
0  w  30
1  w  42
2  w  54
3  w  68
```

Comment: How do you expect us to understand this code dump and know what you're trying to do? How about putting in the effort to explain what you're trying to do, along with expected output. This is not a code refactory service.

Comment: This belongs in https://codereview.stackexchange.com.